# Form field values sum in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get this to work for a project I'm doing. Basically I'm trying to get the values in the "Revenue" fields to total at the bottom in the "Total Revenue" field.

I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jY6P/36/) which hopefully will make it easier to understand-

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">April</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="form-control" name="AprilInput" placeholder="eg. 35,328" type="text" id="AprilInput"></input>
              </div>
            </div>

            <label class="control-label col-md-1">Revenue</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="form-control" name="Output" id="AprilOutput" placeholder="0" type="text" readonly></input>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">May</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="form-control" name="MayInput" placeholder="eg. 35,328" type="text" id="MayInput"></input>
              </div>
            </div>

            <label class="control-label col-md-1">Revenue</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="form-control1" name="Output" id="MayOutput" placeholder="0" type="text" readonly></input>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">June</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="form-control" name="JuneInput" placeholder="eg. 35,328" type="text" id="JuneInput"></input>
              </div>
            </div>

            <label class="control-label col-md-1">Revenue</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="form-control1" name="Output" id="JuneOutput" placeholder="0" type="text" readonly></input>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>

<br/>

<span class="form-horizontal">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="widget-container fluid-height clearfix">
      <div class="heading">
        <i class="icon-reorder"></i>Annual Total
      </div>
      <div class="widget-content padded">

      <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-6">Total Revenue</label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input class="form-control" name="TotalOutput" id="TotalOutput" placeholder="0" type="text" readonly></input>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: An observation - you do not close input tags in the way you are, they are self closing tags, so <input /> NOT <input></input>

Comment: Can you show your JS code as well please.

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle @putvande http://jsfiddle.net/2jY6P/36/

Comment: Thanks everyone! Solved it now, I'm pretty new to all this so still miss a lot of basic stuff unfortunately... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tidy the code up a little:

```
   function SetupInput(obj,output,sumfunction){
        $(obj).keyup(function(){
            var n = parseInt($(this).val());
            var n = this.value.replace(/,/g, "");

            if(n <= 155000) {
                $(output).val(numberWithCommas((n/100*70).toFixed(0)));
            }
            else if(n <= 175000) {
                $(output).val(numberWithCommas((n/100*75).toFixed(0)));
            }
            else {
                $(output).val(numberWithCommas((n/100*80).toFixed(0)));
            }
            sumfunction();
        });
    }
    SetupInput($('#AprilInput')[0],$('#AprilOutput')[0],calculateSum);
    SetupInput($('#MayInput')[0],$('#MayOutput')[0],calculateSum);
    SetupInput($('#JuneInput')[0],$('#JuneOutput')[0],calculateSum);
    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    }



function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".form-control1").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        var value=this.value.replace(',','');//remove ','

        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
            console.log(this.id,sum);
        }
    });

    //.toFixed() method to roundoff the final sum
    $("#TotalOutput").val(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```

Check out the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2jY6P/43/

Answer (score 1):

You are looping though `Output` tag. Change it to `.form-contol`:

```
$(".form-control").each(function() { /* ... */ }
```

And not .html, but .val():

```
`$("#TotalOutput").val(sum.toFixed(0));`
```

Answer (score 0):

i edited you code: http://jsfiddle.net/2jY6P/38/

changed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
        //handler to trigger sum event


            $("input[name='Output']").keyup(function(){

                calculateSum();
            });

    });

    function calculateSum() {

        var sum = 0;
        //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
        $("input[name='Output']").each(function() {

            //add only if the value is number
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }

        });
        //.toFixed() method to roundoff the final sum
        $("#TotalOutput").val(sum.toFixed(0));
    }
```

`$('Output')` should be input `$("[name='Output']")`

> $("#TotalOutput").html(sum.toFixed(0));

should be   `$("#TotalOutput").val(sum.toFixed(0));`

Comment: thanks for that. For some reason when the value is in the 1000's it doesn't calculate (or add commas- I thought they'd carry through?).

Comment: becouse you get the number with a ', ' covert it to a . before the +=

Answer (score 0):

I put some changes in

http://jsfiddle.net/2jY6P/39/

```
$(document).keyup(function() {
    var sumRevenue = 0;
    $.each($(".revenue"), function() {
       var val = $.trim($(this).val());
       if(val != "")
           sumRevenue += parseFloat(val); 
    });
    $("#sumrevenue").val(sumRevenue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Cracker0dks! However it's not coping with the commas (when the value gets to the 1000's) too well and I really need them in there. I thought they'd carry through to the total also.

Comment: because point is in use normal... update with replace comma function: http://jsfiddle.net/2jY6P/51/

Answer (score 0):

```
   function calculateTotalREv(){ 
      var totalRev = 0;
  $("input[name='Output']").each(function() {
    totalRev = eval(total+parseFloat($(this).val()));
  });
      alert(totalRev);
    }
    calculateTotalREv();
```